# msg.sender needs to be equal as an address from array. (solidity)

Tags: solidity

I only want teachers be able to add a new class. ( function addClass() )

How do i check if msg.sender is equal to an address in the teachers array?

````
contract school {
    address public owner;
    address[] public teachers;

    mapping(uint => Class) public classes;

    struct Class {
        uint id;
        address teacher;
        address[] pupils;
    }

    constructor() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function addTeacher(address _address) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        teachers.push(_address);
    }

    function addClass(address _teacher, address[] memory _pupils) public {
        require(msg.sender == teachers);
        classes[1] = Class(1, _teacher, _pupils);
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
address[] public teachers;
```

To this:

```
mapping(address => bool) public teachers;
```

This:

```
teachers.push(_address);
```

To this:

```
teachers[_address] = true;
```

And this:

```
require(msg.sender == teachers);
```

To this:

```
require(teachers[msg.sender]);
```